# Room oneboxes with pings in search results/transcript are messed up

Tags: bug, chat, search, onebox, chat-transcript

When a room link is posted into a room, it oneboxes:

[image: Mith's desk onebox]

But when this shows up in search results, it shows up all messed up:

[image]

and

[image]

And in the transcript as well:

[image]

I'm using Google Chrome version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit), on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit).

---

Apparently this isn't only me:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Not even sure what to ask since this shouldn't be client-dependent in any way. I hope others chime in here so we can try narrowing the issue down that way.

Comment: @AdamLear Seems most likely it's trying to insert the mention markup into the title attribute, no?

Comment: @TimStone Ooh, maybe. I just tried it out locally, though, and I still don't see it - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU1mH.png.

Comment: @AdamLear Funnily enough it doesn't do the highlight in the search if you wrote the message mentioning yourself, suspect it's maybe the same for the transcript, heh. Changing the ownership on the message should make it happen if that's the case, then?

Comment: @TimStone Aha, okay. I'll try that tomorrow. (Gotta unbreak some of my local setup first to get user impersonation working reliably again first.) Thanks!

Comment: @Adam Tomorrow Never Dies?

Comment: @AdamLear - is it tomorrow yet?

Comment: @Mithrandir Tomorrow is always just a few hours away somewhere. ;)